# How can I push front and back faces inward without altering the sides?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I've been stuck for a while with this modeling, this is a vape. I've watched modeling tutorials and almost the entire donut series but my head can't figure out this. In the original model; the sides are almost straight while the front and back faces are being pushed inward, creating crevices that the highlight it's catching. Which would be a way to separate the faces so it keeps his original appearance in the sides?

I though the key could be loop cuts but I can't really figure out a proper way to place them

The sides looks something similar to the model on the right but it's more smoother, thicker and rounder in the mouth as you can see in the middle image. I want the push inward to create the crevice of highlight in the front and back faces[image]

I want to basically create the push inwards without altering the sides[image]

This is my mesh, here I added more loop cuts and I tried only selecting the desired vertex to push in but it keeps altering the sides, I'm guessing it has something to do to being connected but I don't know a way to separate them[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can begin with a circle, fill it, extrude, extrude down, mirror:

[image]

Duplicate the top part of your circle, rotate so that it's horizontal and stick it to the bottom:

[image]

Extrude down:

[image]

Bevel the angle:

[image]

Rework the topology:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Comment: Sweetly done. Not as obvious as you make it look.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean, what step is not obvious according to you?

Comment: Clobbering through with a bevel for the curvature to vertical, while keeping the count right  to connect up, without disturbing the even distribution in the horizontal circle.

Comment: I think I've got the idea of everything except the horizontal circle step, am I missing something in that step? How did you made the circle fix perfectly and joined both bottom sides?  I think mine it's ending a bit smaller

Comment: Yes you need to duplicate 7 vertices of the top circle, rotate it, scale it up a bit, activate the Auto Merge and the Snap To vertex options and stick it to the bottom

Comment: Did you start with 32 vertex in the circle? I think I'm seeing less in yours. I'm guessing that with duplicating the vertices you mean to paste them in the squared face in the top part evenly?  I'm sorry, I'm using all my few neurons to understand that part

Comment: it was a 16 vertices circle, it's always better to begin with as less vertices as possible, and 16 vertices are enough

Comment: hey there! hope you're still there, in the part where you bevel the angle, how did you put the edge so it warps around the circle and bottom part so you can bevel the angle? I'm having problems setting mine. I've recreated the mesh a lot of times already in case I messed up lol

Comment: @Omaren Check my tuto here: https://youtu.be/7u4gwYFCEqM

Comment: I was definitely not going the right direction. Ty so much for the help! One more thing, excuse my novice but in the part where I place a knife cut in the middle of the circle, I'm only able to place it halfway in the middle. Do you have any idea of why is this happening? I already merged by distance and I don't have inner faces in the mesh

Comment: @Omaren I don't know why, maybe share the object?

Comment: sure! https://www.filemail.com/d/mgemqdvnyylsxfm I will try redoing it again maybe there's something I got wrong. thank you so much for your patience

Comment: Could you please tell what knife cut you're talking about? At what minute of the video? I can cut the vertical edge if this is what you're talking about, also, after K press A to cut orthogonally, and C to cut through

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a row (or two) of front faces where you need that inward push.
2. Press `I` to insert faces.
3. Select (if not selected) new, inner faces, and press `E`+`Y` to extrude faces along global Y axis.
4. Push them inwards.

*For symmetrical objects try to always use mirror modifier to avoid extra work.